# an easy way to calculate d-volumes

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, probability, geometry

If I have a function $f:\mathbb{R}^d\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and I want to show that for all $[a_1,b_1]\times\cdots\times[a_d,b_d]\subset[0,1]^d$ the $f$-Volume is non-negative or non-positive, that is 
$$ \sum_{\mathbf{z}\in\Pi_{i=1}^d\{a_i,b_i\}} (-1)^{N(\mathbf{z})} f(\mathbf{z}) \gtreqqless 0$$
Where $N(\mathbf{z})=|\{k:z_k=a_k\}|$. Is there an easy way in general to do this or do you have to go through a case by case consideration. In my case I am interested in $f = max(x_1,x_2,x_3)$.

Comment: Actually in my case of the $\max$ function one can do it for the $d=2$ case and iterate the result in $d=3$, i.e. $(x,y)\mapsto\max(u,x,y)$ has negative volume and the volume of $(z,x,y)\mapsto\max(u,x,y)$ consists of twice the volume of $(x,y)\mapsto\max(u,x,y)$